# Supplying a parameter to a GET_LOCK query in a C# Typed TableAdapter query

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, innodb

I am trying to maintain data consistency across multiple automated services accessing a single MySQL (InnoDB) database. Currently, I am trying to accomplish this using GET_LOCK. I am working with auto-generated typed datasets, and have configured the following query:

```sql
SELECT GET_LOCK('@id', 1)
```

The adapter also accepts an `Int32` as a parameter. The problem is that the `'@id'` field is interpreted as a string literal, so I cannot get a dynamically assigned lock string. My question is if this is even possible.

My current workaround is something along the lines of:

```cs
DataSetTableAdapters.myTableAdapter typedAdapter = new DataSetTableAdapters.myTableAdapter();

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand selectCommand_backup = typedAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand;

typedAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
typedAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = typedAdapter.Connection;
typedAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT GET_LOCK('{0}_{1}', 1)", tableName, id);
typedAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

typedAdapter.Connection.Open();
typedAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
typedAdapter.Connection.Close();

typedAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand_backup;
```

I'm also open to other ideas. I want to prevent conflict resolution if possible, since it would be challenging to handle for an automated system.